# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using [django-dbbackup](https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup) to back up my postgresql database to my s3 bucket. It's connected to my S3 bucket via the following settings:

draft1.settings.py

```
DBBACKUP_STORAGE = 'draft1.aws.utils.BackupRootS3BotoStorage'
DBBACKUP_S3_BUCKET = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
DBBACKUP_S3_ACCESS_KEY = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
DBBACKUP_S3_SECRET_KEY = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

draft1.aws.utils

```
BackupRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='backup')
```

Bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow All",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny All Actions On All But Media and Static Unless Defined User",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/media/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/static/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/media_thumbnail/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to back it up to the `backup` folder.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 116, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 88, in _save_new_backup
    self.write_to_storage(outputfile, filename)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/_base.py", line 88, in write_to_storage
    self.storage.write_file(file, path)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbbackup/storage.py", line 82, in write_file
    self.storage.save(name=filename, content=filehandle)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 452, in _save
    self._save_content(obj, content, parameters=parameters)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 467, in _save_content
    obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=put_parameters)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 513, in object_upload_fileobj
    ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 431, in upload_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 73, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 233, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 126, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 150, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py", line 692, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 324, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/zorgan/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 622, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You need to have IAM permissions to put object.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by adding permissions for `s3:PutObjectAcl` to the IAM policy.

Recent versions of `boto3` & `django-storages` (which `django-dbbackup` uses) set the default ACL per object during each `PutObject` operation. So you need permissions for putting the object *and* updating the ACL.

Here's an example policy based on the one in the question:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow All",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have s3:* but still getting same issue